# Undefined Index only on textbox, <select> works fine

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

> NOTICE: undefined index <---- Only on textbox and hidden
>
> It seems that values inside my textbox and hidden fields are not being submitted but 
>   the select filled is passed

release.php

```
<form name="process_release"  action="content/process_release.php"  onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-offset-3" align="center">
<table class="table">
    <caption><h2>Releasing</h2></caption>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Item (Description) :</label></td><td><input type="text" name="Releasing_item" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>            
        <td><label>No of Items :</label></td><td><select name="Releasing_pieces" >                                      <option value="1">1</option>
                                    <option value="2">2</option>
                                    <option value="3">3</option>      
                                    </select></td>  
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Office :</label></td><td><input type="text" name="Releasing_office" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><label>Received by :</label></td><td><input type="text" name="Releasing_personnel" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <input type="hidden" name="Releasing_pointer" value="Released" />
    </tr>
</table>
    <div>   
        <button type="submit" value="submit" name="send" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
        <button type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-default" >Clear</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

process_release.php

```
<?php
 include ('../required/connect.php');

 if (isset($_POST['Releasing_item'])){
 $item = $_POST['Releasing_item'];
 $pieces = $_POST['Releasing_pieces'];
 $office = $_POST['Releasing_office'];
 $personnel = $_POST['Releasing_personnel'];
 $pointer = $_POST['Releasing_pointer'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO tracking (item, pieces, office, personnel, pointer) VALUES ('$item','$pieces','$office','$personnel','$pointer')";

  if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
  print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"; 
  print "alert('Request Successful!')"; 
  print "</script>";

  mysql_close($con);
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; URL=listings.php'>";
  }
 else
  {
   mysql_close($con);
     print "<script type=\"text/javascript\">"; 
     print "alert('Database Error!')"; 
     print "</script>";
     echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1; URL=../index.php'>";
      } 

?>
```

> NOTICE: undefined index <---- Only on textbox and hidden
>
> It seems that values inside my textbox and hidden fields are not being submitted but 
>   the select filled is passed

Comment: Have you printed the full `$_POST` array? See if there is anything curious going on in there.

Comment: $_POST is empty, even tried var_dump($_POST), it is NULL

Comment: Undefined index for whch textbox? On all of them? Does it give you a line error? Oh and your missing the `</form>` int he html you provided.

Comment: i just forgot to post the </form> but its in the code. all the textbox and hidden field doesnt pass the values. there are no errors on the select field, it has value. i've tried $_GET and $_REQUEST and $_SESSION same error occurs. as you can see the code is syntactically correct. the problem is that why is that it doesn't pass the values in textboxes and hidden field yet passing values on the select field.

Comment: And what if you tried to submit the form normally instead of using the `onsubmit` see if it works then. Probably going something wrong over there.

Comment: still the same error, i tried to quote it inside <?php code here...?>, it work only once, my database updated just once, and came back to the same error, the textbox and hidden fields passes a NULL value. thanks for all the help i appreciated it. hope there is someone who can explain this.